# Selector of UISegmentedControl not triggered for event UIControlEventValueChanged in ios 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector, uisegmentedcontrol, ios11

I have a `UIToolbar` and added few `UISegmentedControl` to it. My problem is my `selector` for `UISegmentedControl` is not getting called in ios 11. But it works fine in IOS 10 and lower versions.

I have a `UITextField` for which I have a date picker as a input view and I have added this tool bar as assesory view. When I click done button in toolbar I set the value of `UITextField`.

```
        UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 50)];
        [toolBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        doneButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:"done"  ]];
        doneButton.momentary = YES;
        doneButton.frame =CGRectMake(toolBar.frame.size.width - 50,5 , 30, toolBar.frame.size.height- 2 *5);
        [doneButton setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];
        doneButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(donePressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [toolBar addSubview:doneButton];
```

The `donePressed` method never gets called in ios 11.0 but the same code works fine in lower ios versions.

Kindly advice any fix.

Comment: Put code of donePressed() method

Comment: It's simple -(void)donePressed{}.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in following way and its working find with iOS 11.1. Selector action `donePressed` is properly called upon value change event of SegmentControl

```
//  ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

  @property IBOutlet UISegmentedControl * doneButton;

@end


//  ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController () {

}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupToolbar];
}


-(void)setupToolbar {
    self.doneButton.momentary = YES;
    [self.doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(donePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

-(void)donePressed:(UISegmentedControl *)segmentControl {
    NSLog(@"segmentControl index - %ld",segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex);
}
@end
```

Storyboard - View controller interface & IBOutlet connection:

[image]

Here is alternate solution - how to handle selector programatically with toolbar. Hope this may work for you.

```
-(void)setupToolbar{
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);


    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *item1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(donePressed:)];
    item1.tag = 1;

    UIBarButtonItem *item2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(donePressed:)];
    item2.tag = 2;

    NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [items addObjectsFromArray:@[item1, flexibleItem, item2]];
    [toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:toolbar];

}

-(void)donePressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {
    NSLog(@"barButtonItem tag - %ld",barButtonItem.tag);
}
```

Comment: Kindly try the same case programmatically with Xcode 9 and ios 11 device.

Comment: Thanks kurnal for info and I have updated the question.

Comment: Add constants like 10 to padding.

Comment: Try alternate solution.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution. Is it working with UISegmentedControl?

Comment: No, if we add segment controller then it also adds, UIToolBarContentView over whole toolbar, which covered segment controller and interrupts user interaction for segment control.

Comment: Is this new to ios 11 if yes then how to solve this and make it to work ? .